# Using @@search Page as Homepage

Tags: plone

We want to customize the Plone site homepage, making it Google style looking, for its major usage is to search contents. The nearest base is the result of /@@search browser view. Is there any quick and recommended way to realize such customization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `search` to `available view methods` in the `ZMI -> portal_types -> Plone Site`:

[image]

Select the `search` view from the `display menu`:

[image]

Enjoy search view

[image]

Bonus points for exporting the customization to a file system add-on via `ZMI -> portal_setup`

Comment: Cool, moar screenshots! You could crop them a little, though. Oh, and red [hand-drawn circles and arrows](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/140890) are a thing here on SO. :-P

Comment: Go easy on the bold though.. use bold sparingly if you can.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can set the `@@search` view as default view on your plone site root:

- Go to `http://your.domain/site/manage_propertiesForm`
- If there is a `layout` property, set as value `@@search`
- If there is no `layout` property, create a new one with this name, the type `string` and use the value `@@search`

You can then style the search form with CSS to your needs. 
You can make the customizations more specific by using the CSS-selector `.template-search.portaltype-plone-site #searchform`.